# pick up the most value element from matix matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, max

I have matrix nx3 like this

```
A = [ 1 3 50;
      1 4 80;
      1 6 75;
      2 3 20;
      3 6 10;
      6 8 20;
      6 9 99;
      . . .
      . . .
    ]
```

I want to check the first index that have same
 => check the third element and pick the maximum value and re arrange matrix

it should be like

```
Ans = [1 4 80;
       2 3 20;
       6 9 99;
       . . .
      ]
```

I was thinking use max() check to on the third element but how can I detect the first element on matrix that are repeated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce the same results as [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22262306/3382783)

```
Ans = sortrows(A, 3);
[~, J] = unique(Ans(:,1));
Ans = Ans(J,:);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
%// Obtain unique values of col 1. Each value will determine a group of rows:
ii = unique(A(:,1));
%// For each group of rows, compute maximum of column 3. This is done efficiently
%// with accumarray. Use its sparse option to avoid memory problems , in case
%//  values of column 1 are very disperse:
kk = nonzeros(accumarray(A(:,1),A(:,3),[],@max,[],true));
%// Select indices of rows whose column 3 contains the maximum of the group
%// determined by column 1. This is done efficiently using bsxfun twice:
m = any(bsxfun(@eq, A(:,1).', ii) & bsxfun(@eq, A(:,3).', kk));
%// Build result:
result = A(m,:);
```

In your example:

```
result =

     1     4    80
     2     3    20
     3     6    10
     6     9    99
```